# google-search autocomplete dialog background is showing previous view elements

Tags: android

I'm implementing an embedded autocomplete google dialog for google places and when I click on it, it shows the background like  described in the picture, is it possible to set a background to the pop-ed up window so the user doesn't see the duplicate?

[image]

The code is taken from GitHub [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/blob/master/PlaceCompleteFragment/Application/src/main/java/com/example/google/playservices/placecompletefragment/MainActivity.java)